# swift segue undeclared type breaks the code

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have been searching every where for a solution but i can't find it and when i look at my code and others it looks as it should be looking.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "helpUpdateProfile" ){
        var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as DetailVC;
        detailVC.toPass = "help"

    }
}
```

It seems to be just on the line that says

```
var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as DetailVC;
```

DetailVC is getting the error, i have no idea what type to declare this, also i have not find any one doing that in this code. I would really like to know what type to declare it.

i am using ios7.1 and 8+ for this app with xcode 6.x latest stable version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should post the error message, second be sure that `DetailVC` is selected in class of your viewController

[image]

Comment: i see the issue here, i forgot to add the detailvc as custom class of the viewcontroller i want to pass the var to.

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to force the cast with:

```
var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
```

Notice the ! after the as.

Or you can do:

```
if let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailVC {
    detailVC.toPass = "help"
}
```

Notice the ? after the as.

segue.destinationViewController returns a UIViewController. What you are doing with the "as" is downcasting the UIViewController to your subclass of UIViewController. The Swift compiler is not able to determine if a downcast between a class and one of its subclasses will succeed. If you know with absolute certainty the type destinationViewController, you can force the downcast with as!. However, if the downcast fails at runtime, your application will crash.  The safer option is to use optional binding and if let with as?. For more information you can read about as on the [Apple Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23)

Comment: there is one more issue, when i println(toPass) the var toPass:String! the consol is printing our nil. i have set everything as it should i think but i am getting nothing back. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you placing your println(toPass)? Is it in the init of DetailVC?

Comment: i have add it to the viewdidappear, please tell me how i should excecute it. i also tried it in the viewdidappear. I am still very new to swift, it is nothing like php or js, well more than js. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Give this a try. In your prepareForSegue method right after  detailVC.toPass = "help"   put in the following:    println(detailVC == nil)   Let me know what is printed to the console.

Comment: i will give that a try

Comment: i have run the line in the code block, and it puts uot nothing so i guess there is a value set in detailsVC. However i needed to make it detailsVC!.toPass = "help" or i get an error.

Comment: i have also just tried println(deatailsVC) and that is also not printing anything to the consol for some reason. looks like it is not setting any value at this point.